# css selector: first paragraph's first letter inside a div

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

```
<div>
 <p>
  Once upon a time..
 </p>
 <p>
  A beautiful princess..
 </p>
</div>
```

**How can I select (in my css) the first letter of the first paragraph inside this div??**

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
div p:first-of-type:first-letter { font-weight: bold; }
```

Answer (score 8):

In some cases you may have a header or some other elements types before the `<p>` For example:

```
<div>    
<h1>My Great Title</h1>
<p>
In my younger years I was a great man, but all that changed when I saw...
</p>
<p>
I struck him for shaming my name, my family, my life. It was a shameful...
</p>
</div>
```

So in this case, `p:first-child` won't work for some reason, at least not in Chrome or Safari.

So instead you'll want to use this:

```
div p:first-of-type:first-letter{
/* add your awesome code here */
}
```

Thank you for your time.

[first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type)

Comment: Thanks for this. :first-of-type is definitely better in a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS `:first-letter` pseudo-element to apply style to the first letter of a block-level element.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would add at least a class to the element you want the first-letter styling to be applied to.  I'm sure you can do a css rule for the first paragraph of the first div; but if you happen to have another div with a paragraph at the beginning, then it is going to be applied to all of them.  In other words, without using a class/id in your selector, it will be applied to the first letter of the first paragraph of **EVERY DIV** (which might not be the behavior you're looking for).  So I would recommend this:

```
<div>
 <p class="FirstLetter">
  Once upon a time..
 </p>
 <p>
  A beautiful princess..
 </p>
</div>
```

And then in your css:

```
.FirstLetter:first-letter {
   // styling rules here
}
```

But if my intuition is incorrect and you know for sure that this is what you're looking for, then @Demian Brecht's answer should do fine.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's actually really simple:

```
div p:first-letter
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS :first-letter Selector

```
div p:first-letter{
 color:blue;   
}
```

[Working example HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rnvjD/)

*Note: The following properties can be used with :first-letter*

font properties,
color properties, 
background properties,
margin properties,
padding properties,
border properties,
text-decoration,
vertical-align (only if float is 'none'),
text-transform,
line-height,
float,
clear

Answer (score -1):

You can directly target the first letter of the entire div:

```
div:first-letter {
    color: red;
}
```

demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRoypa