# How to use a CSS :first-letter pseudo-element in a <div> paragraph

Tags: css, html, pseudo-element

I'm trying to use a CSS :first-letter pseudo-element in a web page to enlarge and colorize the first letter of a paragraph (W), the only thing is that it's in a DIV tag and it's not displaying correctly. I have been to W3C schools and looked at the following here at Stackoverflow ([css selector: first paragraph's first letter inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721730/css-selector-first-paragraphs-first-letter-inside-a-div) and [css first-letter exclude other tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894998/css-first-letter-exclude-other-tags)), but these don't seem to resolve my problem (more than likely I don't have the CSS setup correctly is my guess).  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
div homepara:first-letter {
font-size: 36px;
color: darkblue;
}
```

Here is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div class="homepara">Welcome to This Test Page.
</div>
```

Comment: Typo in your question? Classes need a `.` prefix. Works fine if you fix that http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2VBkU/

Comment: You are missing de dot before `homepara`. It is a Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `div.homepara:first-letter`. When you want to address a div with a class add a `.` between then.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qHE77/)

Comment: Thanks Bill F and Sajad Lfc for your responses, but Itay Gal appears to have got to it first. I appreciate all the assistance "everyone" gave to this question, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector isn't written correctly. Should be:

```
div.homepara:first-letter {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: darkblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.homepara:first-letter
```

you just missed a '.' before the class name and there should not be space between the `.classname` and the `div`

i.e..  `div.classname`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2thLf/)